# Importing Python module from desktop, inexperienced programmer

Tags: function, filenames, filepath, python-import, python-3.5

First off I have very little Python experience and don't understand much about the terminology. Secondly I have never had to use a file path in Python before and therefore related terminology and methods may need to be explained (or have an easy to understand link, that isn't too strong in pythonic terminology like the Python Docs are).

I'm using modular programming and my functions are separate into three different files all in one file on my desktop `C:\Users\User\Desktop\Folder_name\file1.py`.

I plan on using all of the functions within and as such would like it to work similar to `import random`.

Comment: So what have you tried, what doesn't work?

Comment: I did a lot of research but it was all too technical for me to be able to put into action. I simply tried writing the file_path instead of just the module_name e.g.C:\Users\User_name\Desktop\Folder_name\File1.py.

I tried copying stuff in from the web but didn't understand if anything needed changed and if so what. e.g. Using what @Jeff L. said as an example I might write the entire file_path in place of `path` or file_name in place of `__file__`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is your python file doesn't appear in python search path. 
A few ways to solve.

1. As @Jeff says:

> ```
> import os
> path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
> sys.path.append(path)
> ```

this one will add the current file's directory to the search path in the current run context. With these lines in file `/path/b.py`, you can use `/path/a.py` or any python program in `/path/`.

2. Using IDEs function for it. Just run it from your IDE, they will fill the path.
3. Put your python file into any search path directory. This fulfiil your demand that `using all of the functions within and as such would like it to work similar to import random`. However it will make you running environment dirty. Better to use `virtualenv`.

Comment: Thank's for the help, this is exactly what I needed.

It took me a while to get it to work because some of my files names had spaces and I didn't know that would affect anything.

Answer (score 0):

If the dependent modules are in the same folder as the script you are executing:

```
import os
path = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
sys.path.append(path)
```

If they're in a different spot you can just specify path to something manually, but you should try to make it robust to moving around by defining the path in relation to where you execute from.

Comment: @kroderia
I also had to add sys to the import statment, is that how it's supposed to be done?

Comment: Ah yes sorry, I used sys without showing the import. You did it right.